# intl-tel-input "grunt img" command not working

Tags: javascript, npm, gruntjs, imagemagick, intl-tel-input

I am using intl-tel-input to create a control to display mobile numbers.
because the flags are realy small, I need to have them bigger.

As they describe here: https://codepen.io/jackocnr/full/ONXWgQ

I should run `grunt img` and `grunt css` to do this.
however the `grunt img` command fails and I get this error

```
 C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\evenizer\lib\evenizer.js:43
         throw err;
         ^

 Error: Command failed:
     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\evenizer\node_modules\imagemagick\imagemagick.js:88:15)
     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
   timedOut: false,
   killed: true,
   code: null,
   signal: 'SIGKILL'
 }
```

I have

- installed ImageMagick,
- ran the commands as administrator
- ran `npm install evenizer -g`

I am probbably forgetting something silly, but I do not know what.

website: https://intl-tel-input.com/

github: https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty easy.

just run `grunt img --force`
even with the exceptions thrown it will work for enlarging the images.

ofcourse the exceptions are not realy motivating.